# When showing label with button, which of the two needs a "bolder" font?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, labels, font, font-weight

Hope you have a wonderfall day!

Is it a personal preferences? a UI concern? or there is some known facts about this topic that i'm not aware of?

I'm curious about this 2 related topics :

1) **When displaying a label with a button(sample from my iOS app). What would you recommend to have a "bolder" font, the label or the button?**

2)  **Should the button font type/family be consist thru all the screens?**

[image]

Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jazZRo The first question might belong to graphicdesign.stackexchange.com but the second one should fit correctly here, in my opinion.

Comment: @Alvaro. True but the second question lacks context. It is too broad to give a decent answer and should still be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About [consistency](https://material.google.com/layout/principles.html) I would definetely go for it through all the app. This is a quote which is describing layouts but I think it is applicable in your case too.

> Material design adopts tools from the field of print design, like baseline grids and structural templates, encouraging consistency across environments by repeating visual elements, structural grids, and spacing across platforms and screen sizes.

[Material Design](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html#typography-styles) gives rules on the use of typography. It recommends using Medium size All caps typography for buttons (for english language).

[image: typography]

Answer (score 1):

Second answer first - The font family should be consistent through the application. I see no reason why the answer to the first question should change the answer to the second question

Answer to the first question - this might be specific to use cases that you are targeting. However, I dont recall (maybe I never noticed) buttons having "Bold" text. Button in itself is the primary driver for your action, and there is a lot you can do with the button (color, shape, positioning, size, etc) to drive your goal. But the font type on the button might not play an importan role.

With that said, having the text of the label as bold is also very specific to the use case and the positioning onthe screen. If nothing else is bold on the screen, the label might look out of place, and might lead to confusion/ misunderstanding.